# Threading access to various buffers

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this, but I'm getting a bit stuck in figuring out exactly what it is that I'm trying to do, so I'm going to explain what it is, what I'm thinking I want to do, and where I'm getting stuck.

I am working on a program that has a single array (Image really), which per frame can have a large number of objects placed on an image array. Each object is completely independent of all other objects. The only dependency is the output, in theory possible to have 2 of these objects placed on the same location on the array. I'm trying to increase the efficiency of placing the objects on the image, so that I can place more objects. In order to do that, I'm wanting to thread the problem.

The first step that I have taken towards threading it involves simply mutex protecting the array. All operations which place an object on the array will call the same function, so I only have to put the mutex lock in one place. So far, it is working, but it is not seeing the improvements that I would hope to have. I am hypothesizing that this is because most of the time, the limiting factor is the image write statement.

What I'm thinking I need to do next is to have multiple image buffers that I'm writing to, and to combine them when all of the operations are done. I should say that obscuration is not a problem, all that needs to be done is to simply add the pixel counts together. However, I'm struggling to figure out what mechanism I need to use in order to do this. I have looked at semaphores, but while I can see that they would limit a number of buffers, I can envision a situation in which two or more programs would be trying to write to the same buffer at the same time, potentially leading to inaccuracies.

I need a solution that does not involve any new non-standard libraries. I am more than willing to build the solution, but I would very much appreciate a few pointers in the right direction, as I'm currently just wandering around in the dark...

To help visualize this, imagine that I am told to place, say, balls at various locations on the image array. I am told to place the balls each frame, with a given brightness, location, and size. The exact location of the balls is dependent on the physics from the previous frame. All of the balls must be placed on a final image array, as quickly as they possibly can be. For the purpose of this example, if two balls are on top of each other, the brightness can simply be added together, thus there is no need to figure out if one is blocking the other. Also, no using GPU cards;-)

Psuedo-code would look like this: (Assuming that some logical object is given for location, brightness, and size). Also, assume, that isValidPoint simply finds if the point should be on the circle, given the location and radius of said circle.

```
global output_array[x_arrLimit*y_arrLimit)
void update_ball(int ball_num)
{
  calc_ball_location(ball_num, *location, *brightness, *size); // location, brightness, size all set inside function
  place_ball(location,brightness,size)
}

void place_ball(location,brighness,size)
{
  get_bounds(location,size,*xlims,*ylims)
  for (int x=xlims.min;x<xlims.max;y++)
  {
    for (int y=ylims.min;y<ylims.max;y++)
    {
      if (isValidPoint(location,size,x,y))
      {
        output_array(x,y)+=brightness;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i think it is important what sort of objects you render. If they're large, e.g. comparable to the size of the image itself, than chances are that no parallelization will give sufficient improvement in speed (while other methods, not involving parallelization, may help a lot). It is also important to understand what the bottleneck is, e.g. whether you use complex methods of the underlying image manipulation library or just set pixel by pixel.

Comment: They are all small, but not so small that some of them won't overlap. Each one will take up to 1/64th of the size of final image array, measured on each size. I'm also aware that I'm probably bottle-necking my code in other places, but my time to improve this is extremely limited, and the other bottlenecks would take much longer to resolve...

Comment: Well, why not optimize the way the balls are rendered to start with? One doesn't really have to go through all the points in the image, only though those in the bounding box of the ball, right? Otherwise, for such applications twalbergs answer is valid -- let a thread process a line at a time.

Comment: @Mikhail: In reality, I'm not going through every point, but to come up with a simple example to show what I'm trying to do, it was the best I could come up with given a few minutes... Still, I've improved my example.

Comment: I see. Still, the line-wise parallelization should work fine. Especially if you have 4 cores or less.

Comment: And by the way, do you actually add up the brightness values or is that a simplification? That does make a lot of difference.

Comment: The circles is the simplification, but in essence, the numbers are added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing any speed up with the current design is that, with a single mutex for the entire buffer, you might as well not bother with threading, as all the objects have to be added serially anyway (unless there's significant processing being done to determine what to add, but it doesn't sound like that's the case). Depending on what it takes to "add an object to the buffer" (do you use scan-line algorithms, flood fill, or something else), you might consider having one mutex per row or a range of rows, or divide the image into rectangular tiles with one mutex per region or something. That would allow multiple threads to add to the image at the same time as long as they're not trying to update the same regions.

Comment: The benefits are lying in the state. Still, I think I'm seeing how a line wise mutex should work. Thanks!

Comment: Unless the brightness values do get summed up, in which case one can just render half the balls to one buffer and another half to the other buffer and than combine them. Double speed at a cost of double memory is not so bad.

Comment: BTW, @twalberg, i think one wouldn't need a mutex per line with such an approach, since different threads would work with different lines anyway, right?

Comment: @MikhailKozhevnikov The original question stated that the objects were completely independent, but that "in theory possible to have 2 of these objects placed on the same location on the array", so I don't think there's a guarantee that two objects may not try writing to the same line at once. I suggested groups of lines to reduce the number of locks that needed to be tracked, but generally, finer-grained locking leads to more opportunity for parallelism, although with possibly more overhead. Finding the right balance is the hard part.

Comment: so what you propose is to split all the objects between threads and then synchronize their access to certain regions, e.g. lines?

Comment: @MikhailKozhevnikov That's the initial idea, although depending on how sophisticated one wanted to get, I could also see breaking each object into multiple objects by clipping against drawing regions, or other similar "optimizations" ("quoted" because, while it may make things run faster, it makes the code more complex to write, so it may not be worth the effort - it depends on what the ultimate goal is...).

Comment: i think it would actually be faster to split the image between threads, e.g. even lines are handled by one thread and odd ones by another, since that would not require any synchronization apart from a barrier at the end of rendering.

Comment: Possibly, if there are only two cores to play with. There's a number of different ways it could be done, and usually no one "best" answer, at least without knowing the problem domain in quite a bit more detail...

Comment: This suggestion worked quite well. The actual algorithm for adding an object is complex, but essentially it is a look up table depending on where the centroid was, and what size it is. The mutex protection on a row level worked really well, and has lead to the desired speed up of my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, you have an image member in some object.  Add the, no doubt complex, code to add other image/objects to it. maipulate it, whatever.  Aggregate in all the other objects that may be involved, add some command enun to tell threads what op to do and an 'OnCompletion' event to call when done.

Queue it to a pool of threads hanging on the end of a producer-consumer queue.  Some thread will get the *object, perform the operation on the image/set and then call the event, (pass the completed *object as a parameter). In the event, you can do what you like, according to the needs of your app.  Maybe you will add the processed images into a (thread-safe!!), vector or other container or queue them off to some other thread - whatever.

If the order of processing the images must be preserved, (eg. video stream), you could add an incrementing sequence-number to each object that is submitted to the pool, so enabling your 'OnComplete' handler to queue up 'later' images until all earlier ones have come in.

Since no two threads ever work on the same image, you need no locking while processing.  The only locks you should, (may), need are those internal the queues, and they only lock for the time taken to push/pop object pointers to/from the queue - contention will be very rare.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question - you have only one image, but many operations on different parts.  Similar solution - create and load up a 'partDecriptor' object with operations and a pointer/length/topLeft/bottomRight/whatever to its own bit of the image.